# Why is the following code of implementing Linear Queue using Linked List returning a garbage value and then crashing?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, queue

I have written the functions for enqueuing, dequeuing elements and displaying elements. If I run the code, I am able to push and pop elements properly. But as I chose to display the values of my Queue, it gives me a 10digit value and then the compiler crashes. 
My logic of the display function suggests that we should start from the pointer front and then traverse till the end of the queue till NULL is reached. Please help.

NOTE: Updating the code for everyone to get a better look of it.

```
class Node
{
    int data;
    Node *next;

public:
    Node(int num)
    {
        data=num;
        next=NULL;
    }
    friend class Queue;
};

class Queue
{
    Node *rear, *front;
public:
    List()
    {
        front=0;
        rear=0;
    }

    void enqueue(int num)
    {
        Node *new_node=new Node(num);
        if(front==NULL)
            front=rear=new_node;
        else
        {
            rear->next=new_node;
            rear=new_node;
        }
    }

    void dequeue()
    {
        if(front==NULL)
            cout << "Queue is Empty!";
        else
        {
            Node *temp=front;
            front=front->next;
            delete temp;
        }
    }

    void display()
    {
        Node *temp=front;
        while(temp!=NULL)
        {
            cout << temp->data << " ";
            temp=temp->next;
        }
    }
};

main()
{
    Queue q;
    int ch, num;

    do
    {
        cout << "\n----------\n1. Enqueue\n2. Dequeue\n3. Display\n4. Exit\n----------\n";
        cin >> ch;
        switch(ch)
        {
        case 1:
            {
                cout << "\nEnter the number to push:" << endl;
                cin >> num;
                q.enqueue(num);
                break;
            }

        case 2:
            {
                q.dequeue();
                break;
            }

        case 3:
            {
                q.display();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    while(ch!=4);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: The thing you're missing here, is your debugger.  I would suggest a read of [this](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and then a couple of hours of trying to work it out yourself before reading any answers here

Comment: Is front initialized? It sounds like front has a garbage value in it.

Comment: dequeue() should check if front is nullptr first.

Comment: The problem could be with code that is not shown. You don't show where front and rear get initialized. Also does the constructor for Node initialize next to nullptr?

Comment: @dbeer both front and rear were intialized to 0 in the constructor of the Queue class where all these 3 functions reside.

Comment: @drescherjm both front and rear were intialized to 0 in the constructor of the Queue class where all these 3 functions reside.

Comment: What about the constructor for Node? Is next initialized to nullptr? If not you have a bug in `enqueue()` adding your root node.

Comment: @drescherjm yup! in the constructor of Node, next is initialized to NULL.

Comment: Then I say its time to use your debugger. I don't think there is anything we can do to help with the current code.

Comment: @drescherjm okay thanks!
we haven't been taught how to use debugger yet in our college. I will try to study it from internet.

Comment: Can you show your `main` function? That would definitely help

Comment: My advice on debugging: Learn how to single step through your code in the debugger. Look at the variables at each step. Pay attention to the pointers.

Comment: @amc176 ok sure! I'll update it!

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks.. Will keep that in mind :)

Comment: I told you about a potential bug in dequeue(). This could cause a crash. I mean if front is null you can't do front->next.

Comment: @drescherjm yeah.. i updated that..still no luck :/

Comment: Can you add the steps you take to reproduce this? I bet that if you add a call to display after each step you'll figure out what your code is doing wrong. (Using a debugger would be better, but maybe this will help while you learn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code sample is incomplete to tell definitively. But my guess is that you don't initialize next member to nullptr and it is initialized by garbage not null value.

Comment: I have initialized next to NULL in the constructor of Node.
Wait, I will update the whole code.

Comment: your updated code contains typo (List constructor in place of Queue), after correction compiles and works just fine with empty and nonempty Queue.

Comment: omg! that was such a silly mistake! thanks a lot!
please update your answer so that i can vote it as the best answer:)

Comment: what compiler are you using? my g++ 5.4.1 outright refuses to compile with List() constructor:
```
error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘List’ with no type [-fpermissive]
     List()
          ^
```

Comment: I am using the IDE code::blocks
I didn't get any warning for the List() constructor at all :/
Mine gave me error on run time..